# rails nested forms unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I've read a couple of other posts for this error here, but no one really fits my problem.

The produced error is

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: practice_id
```

It's happening while I try to build the uebung_maps in the rails console:

```
irb(main):003:0> @p = Practice.new
=> # Practice id: nil, datum: nil, start: nil, end: nil, group: nil, topic: nil, theoab: nil, pracab: nil, action: nil, water: nil, tools: nil, broken: nil, toolkeeper: nil, atw: nil, atfinfo: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):004:0> @p.uebung_maps.build
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: practice_id
    from /home/basti/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in `block in assign_attributes'
```

my models and so on looks like following

**Practice Model**

```
class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :uebung_maps
  has_many :persons
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :uebung_maps
  attr_accessible :uebung_map_attributes, :action, :atfinfo, :atw, :broken, :datum, :end, :group, :pracab, :start, :theoab, :toolkeeper, :tools, :topic, :water
end
```

**Uebung_map Model**

```
class UebungMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :practice
  belongs_to :vehicle
  attr_accessible :person_id, :role_id, :uebung_id, :vehicle_id
end
```

Comment: There is a typo, `@p = Practive.new`should be `@p = Practice.new`

Comment: I've done that right.. edit is also done :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `:practice_id` to your `attr_accessible`, like so:

```
attr_accessible :person_id, :role_id, :uebung_id, :vehicle_id, :practice_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the problem. The column in uebung_map wich should point to Pratice was named uebung_id in stead of practice_id.. now it's working